# Typechecking units of measure in F#

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement, typechecking

I'm trying to wrap my head around units of measure and how they work in typechecking.  In particular, I'd like to typecheck the generalized conversion function they have in the financial examples at tryfsharp.org.  Here is their original function:

```
let convert (rate:decimal<'r>) (value:decimal<'c>) =
    value * rate
```

This seems a bit lacking, since there is no connection between the rate and the value.  Here is my naive update:

```
let convert (rate:decimal<'u/'v>) (value:decimal<'v>) : decimal<'u> =
    value * rate
```

However, when I enter this into the REPL, the type is resolved as the frustratingly general:

```
val convert : rate:decimal<'u> -> value:decimal<'v> -> decimal<'u 'v>
```

Which doesn't stop you at all from doing something stupid, since I can still just happily break my typechecking like so:

```
convert 1.0M<USD/EUR> 1.0M<GBP>
```

Which, rather than erroring, yields the unhelpful

```
val it : decimal<USD GBP/EUR> = 1.0M
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Well, the way your constraints are written, the transformations of the signature are valid (you have `'u/'v*'v = 'u` and the compiler has changed it to `'u*'v = 'u 'v`).  Note that the output units are odd, but still correct.  The problem is that you can always multiply any two sets of numbers with units.

Comment: The F# compiler warns if it makes the code less generic than the type annotations indicate, why doesn't it complain when it makes the code more generic than the type annotations indicate?  That seems to me to be a bigger problem.

Comment: I am not actually convinced that the code is actually more generic.  In your example, setting `'u = USD * GBP / EUR` and `'v=GBP` will fufill the `'u/'v -> -v -> 'u` condition.

Comment: In fact in general, just set `'a='u/'v` and `'b='v` and you transform your first signature to the second.  So the signatures are equivalent

Comment: I'd say handling multiple currencies is not a good example to learn about units of measure

Comment: In general, physical problems (planets with gravity for example) are better suited for learning about units, and are more what they are designed for.

Comment: So let's recast it in terms of physical constants.  I'd like a generic conversion function that takes a value in slugs and a conversion rate which depends on the choice of gravity, foot, and pound.  I'd like to allow `convert 14.6<kg/slug> 10<slug>` but prevent `convert 14.6<kg/slug> 17<lb>`.  Is there any way to describe that relationship?

What's confusing to me is the asymmetry.  I can enforce that the construction of the rate is fine: `val makeRate : numerator:float<'u> -> denominator:float<'v> -> float:<'u/'v>` though now I see you can still do: `makeRate 1<furlong/fortnight> 1<kg/l>`

Comment: So the safety guarantees that come from units-of-measure are based on the system as a whole, not a singular usage.  I'm wondering then what it looks like when you do indeed see the type error, since it would be pretty hard to pinpoint that it actually came from this conversion function.

Comment: It is very easy to see errors - try `1<USD> + 1<EUR>` - this is what the system is designed to protect against as in a physical system, multiplying arbritrary units is fine, but adding them together is not.  I think the problem is that the compiler has no method to know about what units are "simple", as compound units can be defined.